# Storing tokenized text in the db?

Tags: python, caching, postgresql, nlp, tokenize

I have a simple question. I'm doing some light crawling so new content arrives every few days. I've written a tokenizer and would like to use it for some text mining purposes. Specifically, I'm using Mallet's topic modeling tool and one of the pipe is to tokenize the text into tokens before further processing can be done. With the amount of text in my database, it takes a substantial amount of time tokenizing the text (I'm using regex here).

As such, is it a norm to store the tokenized text in the db so that tokenized data can be readily available and tokenizing can be skipped if I need them for other text mining purposes such as Topic modeling, POS tagging? What are the cons of this approach?

Comment: You haven't described your approach clearly enough to get a meaningful answer. Can you give examples of input & output of the tokenizer process and why you believe it is a bottleneck.

Comment: @Terrel, I have edited my question. Hope its clearer now.

Comment: based on your other questions, I have a better picture of what you are trying to accomplish. The kind of regular expressions you were asking about are VERY slow, so I would think existing tokenizers (as suggested by dmcer) would do it faster.  Feedparser and beautifulsoup are the best python solutions for getting text out of blogs to feed into your tokenizer.  And yes, I would cache the output of this phase.

Comment: @Terrel, thank you for your comments. I'll take a look at the existing tokenizers as well as double check on my existing regex. And yea, I'll using feedparser and beautifulsoup at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Caching Intermediate Representations**

It's pretty normal to cache the intermediate representations created by slower components in your document processing pipeline. For example, if you needed [dependency parse trees](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-dependencies.shtml) for all the sentences in each document, it would be pretty crazy to do anything **except** parsing the documents once and then reusing the results.

**Slow Tokenization**

However, I'm surprise that tokenization is really slow for you, since the stuff downstream from tokenization is usually the real bottleneck.

What package are you using to do the tokenization? If you're using Python and you wrote your own tokenization code, you might want to try one of the tokenizers included in **[NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/)** (e.g., [TreebankWordTokenizer](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.tokenize.treebank.TreebankWordTokenizer-class.html)).

Another good tokenizer, albeit one that is not written in Python, is the [PTBTokenizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/process/PTBTokenizer.html) included with the **[Stanford Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml)** and the **[Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml)** end-to-end NLP pipeline.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Perhaps as @Terrel suggested, I used some really slow regex in my own tokenizer (some to tokenize smileys properly). Will check on them. I have tried the ntlk treebankwordtokenizer, but thought maybe I can get my hands dirty on building one myself (based on Penn Treebank conventions).

Answer (score 1):

I store tokenized text in a MySQL database. While I don't always like the overhead of communication with the database, I've found that there are lots of processing tasks that I can ask the database to do for me (like search the dependency parse tree for complex syntactic patterns).